# Error when trying to load XLConnect Package

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

After updating to the latest version of Rstudio (R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) -- "Single Candle") I cannot seem to get the XLConnect Package to load. This is the error message I get:

```
> library('XLConnect')
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
```

R also throws a similar error message when I try to load the rJava package as well. I have tried uninstalling both Java and R and have scoured SO for answers, but nothing seems to work.

I am running macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

Would anyone be willing to offer any help?

Comment: Literally yesterday, I was faced with the same issue (albeit on Windows). IF you need to read/write Excel files, take a look at the openxlsx package. Can read and write Excel files, but does not require Java.

Comment: I've just defaulted to using the 'readxl' package as that allowed me to do what I wanted. I am just worried about in the future when I actually have to use rJave in another package.

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that there is an issue loading `rJava`. Try updating the Java configuration variables via `R CMD javareconf` or `sudo R CMD javareconf`.